customising colours in vtree
I am struggling to figure how to customise colors in vtree R. I found the answer below from this post Change gradient with customise colors
which customises the colours for all levels. But I want to customise colours for a level say am while keeping the gradient colour for cyl.
library(vtree)
vtree(mtcars, "cyl am", rootfillcolor = "yellow",
  specfill = list(
      cyl = c("blue", "green", "yellow"),
      am = c("pink", "brown")
      )
 )

The following codes don't work:
vtree(mtcars, "cyl am", rootfillcolor = "yellow",
  specfill = list( 
             am = c("pink", "brown") 
             )  
 )


vtree(mtcars, "cyl am", rootfillcolor = "yellow",
  gredient=c(TRUE,FALSE),
  specfill = list( 
                  cyl = "blue",
                  am = c("pink", "brown")  
             )  
  )


I'm not sure if I understand. When I run the last example you provided, the root node is yellow, all 3 of the cyl nodes are blue, and the am nodes alternate between pink and brown. Is that not the desired output? Are you getting something different?

@AllanCameron I want cyl have different shades of blue (gradient)

Then simply pass the three shades of blue you want instead of cyl = "blue". If you want to construct a gradient, use colorRampPalette. See my examples below

Thank you @AllanCameron. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to vote you up.

You can just pass the vectors of colors you want for each variable as a named list to the specfill argument.
The vectors must either be length 1 or the same length as the number of levels the variable has. In this example, cyl has 3 levels and am has 2.
If you want to supply just two colors and have a gradient between them, you can generate this with colorRampPalette().
For example, here are 3 distinct colors for cyl:
vtree(mtcars, "cyl am", rootfillcolor = "yellow",
      specfill = list(
        cyl = c("red", "blue", "green"),
        am = c("pink", "brown")
      )
)


And here is a blue gradient, which is actually just a vector of 3 colors created by colorRampPalette:
vtree(mtcars, "cyl am", rootfillcolor = "yellow",
      specfill = list(
        cyl = colorRampPalette(c("navy", "lightblue"))(3),
        am = c("pink", "brown")
      )
)


